# Hibernate Collection chaining

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, collections, hql

I have two Entities

```
University   
   courses

Course
   students
```

i want to access all the students in a university. I tried the following query

```
select u.courses.students from university u
```

i got the following  exception.

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection [university0_.id.courses] with element property reference [students] [ select u.courses.students from com.socialsite.persistence.University u  ]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.DotNode$1.buildIllegalCollectionDereferenceException(DotNode.java:46)
  .....
```

can anyone explain what is wrong with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `u.courses` is a Collection and doesn't have a `students` property (which is a property of a single `Course`).

Answer (score 2):

i figured it out. Thanks pascal

```
   select distinct s
   from University u
     inner join u.courses as c
       inner join c.students as s
```